# How do I enlarge hyperref's reference link boxes to cover additional text around the actual reference counter in a numeric bibliography style?

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

I am using the `memoir` class with a numeric citation style that adds the letter "r" before a reference. A minimal example would be this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcitestyle{open={[r},close={]},citesep={; r}}

\begin{document}

Here is the document's body text. Dummy\citep{Erdos01,lamport94} text. Dummy text.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Erdos01} P. Erd\H os, \emph{A selection of problems and results in combinatorics}, Recent trends in combinatorics (Matrahaza, 1995), Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2001, pp. 1--6.
\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport, \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}. Addison Wesley, Massachusetts, 2nd Edition, 1994.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The superscript citation style is achieved with `natbib`'s `super` option (and I'd like to maintain this setup), and the link boxes around the citation numbers are achieved through `hyperref`.

The reference compiles to a superscript "[r1; r2]", as intended, but hyperref's link boxes cover only the numbers "1" and "2"; how do I make hyperref's boxes cover the entire "r1" and "r2"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Punctuation characters are not part of the link. You can try instead:

```
\renewcommand*{\citenumfont}[1]{r#1}
```